# PHP String reversal without using extra memory

Tags: php

How can i reverse $str= "hello\n" to "olleh\n" without using any extra memory variable?

I looked up for prebuilt functions but they all use memory, also, i think string is immutable so basically can this be done without any tweak or creating a new string is the only option?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Is turning it into an array considered using extra memory?

Comment: @JonLin Technically all strings are already an array so you wouldn't need to turn it into one. They are simply `char` arrays.

Comment: @SeanBright It's a part of an example question given to me for a company recruitment, more than that i am inquisitive about whether something like this can be done or not

Comment: Since PHP strings are immutable, it's impossible to do without creating a new string. If you reassign to the original variable, the old string will become garbage and its memory will be reclaimed immediately.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I don't think anything is immutable in PHP.</strike>
So

```
$str = strrev($str);
```

may be of some use.

Fear the micro-optimization as it will take all your time, for no real result ! :)

Comment: The variable is mutable, not the string itself.

Comment: this will even reverse the '\n' which isn't how it's supposed to be right?

Comment: @Barmar, ok, my bad. Thanks for the info. Arihant, no direct way to do that, you have to extract what you don't want to reverse and store it to reinject later...

Answer (score 3):

I may be overlooking something, but if all your lines end in `\n` I think this might be the shortest method:

```
$str = strrev( trim( $str ) ) . "\n";
```

I'm not sure how much memory is involved though.

Answer (score 0):

How much 'extra memory' you talking here?
PHP has a neat function to flip strings for you : [strrev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)

Simply use

```
$str = strrev($string);
```

If you really wanted you could write a loop to do practically the same thing but that would use memory.

```
<?php
            $string = trim("Some Random string");
            // string length
            $len = strlen($string);
            // make string array
            $stringExp = str_split($string);
            // Loop through and print backwards
            for ($i = $len - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                echo $stringExp[$i];
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Damn... loops memory usage!

Comment: @revo yes very harshly :( just left it for OP to see there are other ways of doing it :P